# Is it possible to logout in Laravel using Curl?

Tags: laravel, curl, logout

**web.php (Inside routes directory)**

```
        Route::get('directLogout', function (Request $request) {

        $user = User::where('email', 'pratik@test.com')->first();
        Auth::login($user,true);

        $path = 'http://localhost/multiframework/public/logout';

        try {
            //Set logout to Server
            $client = new Client([
                'base_uri' => 'http://localhost/multiframework/public',
            ]);

            $token = getCSRFToken();

            $response = $client->request('POST', $path, [
                'form_params' => [
                    '_token' => $token,
                ],
//                'form_params' => [
//                    'token' => $token,   // Tried both. Not working token or _token
//                ],
                'exceptions' => true,
                "headers" => ["Accept" => "application/json",'X-CSRF-Token'=> $token],
            ]);

            return $response->getStatusCode();  // 200 for success, 204 for error
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

});

function getCSRFToken(){
    return csrf_token();
}
```

**Curl Code**

```
$url = "http://localhost/multiframework/public/directLogout";   
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, [CURLOPT_URL => $url, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ["Accept" => "application/json"], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true]);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($res);
die;
```

**Error**

**Client error:** `POST http://localhost/multiframework/public/logout` resulted in a `419 unknown status` response: { "message": "CSRF token mismatch.", "exception": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException", (truncated...)

**Note:** I have also tried to bypass the logout URL from VerifyCsrfToken middleware. It's still not working.

Comment: You say you tried to bypass the CSRF check in the middleware but you don't mention your code in that attempt. Your question is also a bit inconsisntent because you access `http://localhost/multiframework/public/directLogout` but the error is for `http://localhost/multiframework/public/logout` and as an aside you should set up your website properly with a virtual host the directory `public` should never be part of the URL

Comment: Here I am managing a single user with multiple site logins. When I will be logged out on one site it will log out the same user from another site as well.

Suppose we have two websites here called A and B.

So here When I clicked logout in website A,  it will make curl call on website B's  directLogout  URL.

In directLogout url I have logged in the same user which is logged in to website A to get the same user to log out it from website B. 

Then I have called logout url from website B to clear the session.

Comment: if you control both sites it might be easier to create an adminstrative route that does this because when you use cURL from your server you are sending the request as your server so you won't be sending the user's session cookie

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use curl (which is complicated as you must pass the user's session cookie to authenticate the user), it might be easier if you create an API that logs the user out: `/api/logout/{user_id}`

```
$session = Session::where('user_id', $user_id)->delete();
```

If you have set up your session to use database, then the logout process is as easy as deleting the user's session row from the `sessions` table. As soon as the session is deleted (find by `user_id` column), the user will be logged out of that website.

Comment: maybe there would be a little more because unless the user ID is shared between systems, some other token might be required such as the user's email address.

Comment: Email address can be used, too. All you need to do is change how you get the `user_id` as this is needed to find the sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solutions.

I have implemented session base login in my current project.

For that, we need to create a session table in the current database.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session

Made changes in config/session.php and .env file

Change SESSION_DRIVER = database

Added below code

```
        Route::get('directLogout', function (Request $request) {

        $user = User::where('email', 'pratik@test.com')->first();
        Auth::login($user,true);
        Session::where('user_id', Auth::id())->delete();
        Auth::logout();
        $data = [
            'status' => 200,
            'message' => 'User logged out successfully',
        ];    

        return json_encode($data);
        });
```